# Erro with @NotEmpty in a subproject

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I get the error "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'naturezaOperacao'" when I try to validate one bean, but the weird is that I only got this error when I try to validate the bean in a .jar file( a component that my project uses) I have the @NotEmpy in my main project and works fine, All project are using the hibernate-validator-6.0.2.Final

The project works on my dev computer, I try to download the same tomcat that my client is using and my computer runs without problems

[image]

Comment: Check if the tomcat @client has any validator implementation i.e. library in Tomcat/lib

Comment: Might be related to the java 17 move of javax.validation.constraints -> jakarta.validation.constraints